# HTML file and CSS file won't link in localhost

Tags: html, css

The files link when I open them normally but when I open them in localhost the .css file seems to have no effect.

Here's the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="random.css">
```

I've tried the file root as localhost too and still nothing. Any help here?

file structure is C:/Users/Kieran/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/portfolio/random.css
file structure is C:/Users/Kieran/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/portfolio/random.html

HTML file is in the same place.

Entire HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="random.css">
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.html">Kieran Lythgoe Portfolio</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel1" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Image Split</div>
      <div class="panel-body">An image split into difference sections with different links</div>
       <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1"><button onclick="window.location.href='imagesplit.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button></div>

    </div> 

<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel2" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Boolean</div>
      <div class="panel-body";>A simple example of boolean with the use of addition of two numbers</div>
       <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1"><button onclick="window.location.href='boolean.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button></div>

    </div> 

<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel3" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Random</div>
      <div class="panel-body";>A simple example of boolean with the use of addition of two numbers</div>
       <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1"><button onclick="window.location.href='other.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button></div>

    </div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the full file structure please?

Comment: Are the files successfully retrieved from the server?

Answer (score 0):

The `type="text/css"` attribute should be part of the `<link>` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="random.css">
```

And remove the first line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Comment: None of these methods have worked unfortunately. Putting '/' in front of my css file changes things but still doesn't correspond to my css.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>My Website</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="random.css">
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.html">Kieran Lythgoe Portfolio</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel1" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Image Split</div>
      <div class="panel-body">An image split into difference sections with different links</div>
       <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1"><button onclick="window.location.href='imagesplit.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button></div>

    </div> 

<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel2" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Boolean</div>
      <div class="panel-body";>A simple example of boolean with the use of addition of two numbers</div>
       <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1"><button onclick="window.location.href='boolean.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button></div>

    </div> 

<div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel3" style="width: 15%";>
      <div class="panel-heading">Random</div>
      <div class="panel-body";>A simple example of boolean with the use of addition of two numbers</div>
       <div class="panel-footer panel-primary" id="footer1"><button onclick="window.location.href='other.html'" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">CLICK HERE</button></div>

    </div> 

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

**Here is the result without random.css :**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX28V.png

Comment: this didn't work either, I think it may be something to do with xampp like I can't use both at the same time or something?

Comment: Try to copy the code as it is now and put it in the same folder, name it index.html and double click on it .

Comment: @KieranLythgoe I think there is a problem with the bootstrap version , I just edited the code , try it again .

Comment: I managed to fix it, just had to put the css file in its own folder, not sure why it works like that but hey ho. Thank you for taking the time to help me though was very good of you.

Comment: @KieranLythgoe anytime :-D , that's weird ?!? do you use a framework ?